# excel vba look for keywords list based if value lookup exists and then edit the value of another cell

Tags: vba, excel, find, keyword-search

I have a list of guests whom each eats a certain type of vegetables. For instance John,Smith eats potato and tomato. While Bill,Peter eats Carrots,Onions. I have created a list along with keywords that looks like this

[image]

Now, I receive a data extract that has a list of names along with a free text description of the food they ate. Here is what i get

[image]

Unfortunately, I get the names in a format that I do not want like John,Smith (Primary Customer) and I want excel to add the vegetable they ate given it is written in the description. For example, John,Smith (Primary Customer) has the description as: "he had French fries and wedges" and since the description contains a keyword listed in my initial table for the same indivdual then his name will be changed from John,Smith (Primary Customer) to John,Smith-Potato (Primary Customer).

I want excel to check if the name exists in the first table first and then look through the description to find any keywords. This will make sure if the name at hand is not contained in my list then excel will not spend time looking for keywords. Also, if no keyword found then do not edit the name.

this is what I expect to get

[image]

Here is the code tried so faar... I keep getting an error and I didn't reach to the point to validate this code to check if it gives me the results I was looking for.. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub homework()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, keywords() As String, lastRow As Integer, lastRow2 As Integer, c As Variant, x As Integer, y As Integer, k As Variant, cel As Range, descript As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim SrchStr As Variant
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'the sheet that contains keywords which is the sheet i will make
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'the sheet that contains description of food
lastRow = ws1.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lastRow2 = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set SrchRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A1000")
Set descript = ws2.Range("C2:C" & lastRow2)
For x = 2 To lastRow ' this is to the last row in the database i will create
keywords = Split(ws1.Cells(x, 3), ",")
For Each k In keywords
    For Each cel In descript
    For y = 2 To lastRow2
    Do
    SrchStr = Left(ws2.Cells(y, 2), InStr(ws2.Cells(y, 2), " (") - 1)
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing And InStr(ws2.Cells(y, 3), k) <> 0 Then
            ws2.Cells(y, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(x, 1).Value & "-" & ws1.Cells(x, 2).Value
            SrchStr = Nothing
            Exit Do
            End If
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        Next y
    Next cel
Next k
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are going to have to nest some loops. I'd suggest variant memory arrays loaded from the worksheet and the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx). Possibly a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object to keep track of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think something along the lines of the below would work, change the ranges to suit your needs, but it will check the guestname against the list 1st and then assigns the keywords to an array and check those.

```
Sub example1()
Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
Dim GuestName() As Variant, Keywords As Variant
Dim GNi As Integer, Ri As Integer, KWi As Integer

Set WS1 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set WS2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WS1
  GuestName = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
End With

With WS2
  For Ri = 2 To .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'starting at the 2nd row to the last row with data on the sheet
    For GNi = 1 To UBound(GuestName)
      If InStr(1, .Range("B" & Ri), GuestName(GNi, 1)) > 0 Then 'searches for the guestname to match against
        Keywords = WS1.Range("C" & GNi + 1) 'assigns the keywords matching the guestname
        Keywords = Split(Keywords, ",")
        For KWi = 0 To UBound(Keywords)
          If InStr(1, .Range("C" & Ri), Keywords(KWi)) > 0 Then
            'found keyword
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next
End With
End Sub
```